# How to validate array by themselves? (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have an array of data for example in which they have the same id.

```
[
    {
        id: 222,
        name: 'Fff',
    }
    {
        id: 223,
        name: 'Ssss',
    },
    {
        id: 222,
        name: Wwww',
    }
]
```

From the data above, the expected behavior is, it should fail because they have the same id.

Is there a Laravel built-in validation in which we can validate this scenario?

Comment: Hard to say given your example lacks of context. If that's a collection of models, you can use the `unique` rule.

Comment: @shaedrich its from excel collection sir.

Comment: Yes there is a validation `'foo.*.id' => 'distinct'` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-distinct

Comment: @Shahrukh yeah it works. thanks so much. can you post it as answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a validation called distinct to check for duplicate values. For more info https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-distinct

```
'foo.*.id' => 'distinct'
```